# How do I set all the faces on my mesh so they are the same shade?

Tags: uv, 3d-view, shaders, normals, lighting

I created this opening animation using blend keys. (viewport shading)

[image: Origami Shading animation]

When the animation opens up at the end I want all of the triangular faces to be shaded the same colour, as the mesh is now completely flat.

Below is how it looks at currently.

[image: Origami Flat]

Anyone have any idea?

Blender file:

[image]

Comment: As it's now flat the faces should look the same color, unless their color is different?

Comment: In solid mode it's showing them as the same colour. But when I switch to material mode all of the faces are as shown above.

Comment: The material just contains a normal map, which is a paper texture.

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals? In edit mode, SHIFT-N.

Comment: I have. I can get it looking a bit better. but for some reason I can't get them all looking the same.

Comment: can you share the blend file?  I can't reproduce your problem. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Its taking ages to upload to blend exchange. Can you see this? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AucwF5KNl9l5hORNsgDbwbTh9KlBEA?e=yqiPiw

Comment: I've haven't managed to solve it yet. But I've attached the blend file to this post.

Comment: It works if you don't use a normal map. Btw you also didn't pack the normal map into the .blend.

Comment: I know, but I need it to be textured. I don't really see why its causing the different faces to have different reflective qualities

Comment: If there are seams in the UVs, the normal values can differ from face to face, making them reflect light differently

Comment: No seams in the uvs. The uvs are a bit odd I suppose, but I need to keep the uvs the same for my textures to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something resembling a solution. I was able to get the faces to look somewhat the same shade/reflectiveness by rotating the 'normals'.

To rotate the 'normals' of a face, first, go to edit mode, select a face, then from the dropdown go to Mesh->Normals-Rotate. Adjust with your cursor or type in a value.

I couldn't get it to perfectly match, but it was good enough for what I was using it for.